# Lagged (in)dependent variables: 2 time periods

Tags: multiple-regression, panel-data, predictor, lags, dependent-variable

**Summary**

I have a dataset with observations regarding an industrial process in two time periods. My goal is to find predictors of future performance, and I am wondering whether panel data regressions are an appropriate method for my specific case, and if so, whether using only lagged variables on the RHS is appropriate.

**The Setting**

The data consists of a performance score, some variables of interest (I unfortunately do not have a treatment variable) and controls, all of these measured in period 1 & at time 2. The challenge in my setting is causality. While the data is for two periods, the timeline of events is as follows:

1. Performance is measured ($t=1$)
2. Variables of interest are set after measurement ($t=1$)
3. Performance is measured again ($t=2$)
4. Variables of interest are set after measurement ($t=2$)

For my analysis, step 4 is completely irrelevant, since I am not interested in what is done after step 3, but how step 2 - while accounting for step 1 - affects step 3. In other words, I only care about one variable in t=2. I have strong reasons to believe that past performance has a non-zero impact on future performance, so I want to include past performance in the analysis.

**The Question**

Is it appropriate for me to use  $y_{i,t=2}$ for my dependent variable and $t=1$ for the independents (including $y_{i,t=1}$) in a panel regression (i.e. run $y_{i,t=2} = \alpha + \beta_1 y_{i,t=1} + \beta_2 x_{2,i,t=1} + \beta_3 x_{3,i,t=1} +... + errors  $)?

If so, what should I consider/watch out for? If not, what should I do instead?

**Further Details**

The main reason I am asking this here is that I cannot find this situation discussed anywhere, only the opposite situation. In dynamic panel models, a lagged dependent variable is included in the regressors (i.e. $y_{i,t=2} = \alpha + \beta_1 y_{i,t=1} + \beta_2 x_{2,i,t=2} + ... + errors  $), but I do not care about the other regressor values in $t=2$ (because there is no way that performance in that period is affected by variables that are set in response to that performance).
I am most likely not looking for the right terms, I have found a bunch of things on [lagged dependent variables](https://statisticalhorizons.com/lagged-dependent-variables) and dynamic panel models, but this does not describe my setting.

Some more complicated models that require longer time series (ARIMA, most models from financial modeling, etc) are apparently out.

Comment: Why do you have *Panel Model vs. OLS* in your title?

Comment: good point, made an edit. Thanks!